# Highlight parts of text in FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, highlight, flowdocument

I want to highlight some parts of text in a `FlowDocument` based on the search results. What I am doing is getting the indexes where the searched word occures in the text of the `FlowDocument` and then apply background color on the text range starting at the found index, ending at the found index + search word length.

```
TextRange content = new TextRange(myFlowDocument.ContentStart, 
                                  myFlowDocument.ContentEnd);
List<int> highlights = GetHighlights(content.Text, search);

foreach (int index in highlights)
{
    var start = myFlowDocument.ContentStart;
    var startPos = start.GetPositionAtOffset(index);
    var endPos = start.GetPositionAtOffset(index + search.Length);
    var textRange = new TextRange(startPos, endPos);
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, 
               new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
}

TextRange newRange = new TextRange(myFlowDocument.ContentStart, 
                                   newDocument.ContentEnd);
FlowDocument fd = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Parse(newRange.Text);
```

The problem is, that I am searching indexes in the text of the document but when I'm returning the `FlowDocument` the xaml tags are added and I see the highlights moved.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Finaly, inspired by the answer of user007, after making some modifications I managed to highlight all the occurences of a string in a FlowDocument. Here is my code:

```
for (TextPointer position = newDocument.ContentStart;
        position != null && position.CompareTo(newDocument.ContentEnd) <= 0;
        position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward))
{
    if (position.CompareTo(newDocument.ContentEnd) == 0)
    {
        return newDocument;
    }

    String textRun = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    StringComparison stringComparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture;
    Int32 indexInRun = textRun.IndexOf(search, stringComparison);
    if (indexInRun >= 0)
    {
        position = position.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun);
        if (position != null)
        {
            TextPointer nextPointer = position.GetPositionAtOffset(search.Length);
            TextRange textRange = new TextRange(position, nextPointer);
            textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, 
                          new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate using `GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward)` and get `TextPointer`, use this one with previous `TextPointer` to construct `TextRange`. On this `TextRange` you can apply your logic.

What you can't do is use single TextRange from `FlowDocument` for searching text. `FlowDocument` is not only text:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String search = this.content.Text;

        TextPointer text = doc.ContentStart;
        while (true)
        {
            TextPointer next = text.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (next == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            TextRange txt = new TextRange(text, next);

            int indx = txt.Text.IndexOf(search);
            if (indx > 0)
            {
                TextPointer sta = text.GetPositionAtOffset(indx);
                TextPointer end = text.GetPositionAtOffset(indx + search.Length);
                TextRange textR = new TextRange(sta, end);
                textR.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
            }
            text = next;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
it does not work allways, for example if you have list, special characters (\t) are counted by `IndexOf`, but `GetPositionAtOffset` doesn't count them in:

```
•   ListItem 1
•   ListItem 2
•   ListItem 3
```

this line:

```
int indx = txt.Text.IndexOf(search);
```

could be replaced with:

```
int indx = Regex.Replace(txt.Text, 
     "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled).IndexOf(search);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I'm trying your code but it is highlighting only the first occurence of the search text. I'm trying now to modify it to show all the occurences.

Answer (score 0):

`kzub`'s answer did not seem to work for me so I also created a solution expanding on `user007` to highlight all instances of a substring in TextPointer text. It also ignores case and will highlight all matches:

```
    public static void HighlightWords(TextPointer text, string searchWord, string stringText)
    {
        int instancesOfSearchKey = Regex.Matches(stringText.ToLower(), searchWord.ToLower()).Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < instancesOfSearchKey; i++)
        {
            int lastInstanceIndex = HighlightNextInstance(text, searchWord);
            if (lastInstanceIndex == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            text = text.GetPositionAtOffset(lastInstanceIndex);
        }
    }

    private static int HighlightNextInstance(TextPointer text, string searchWord)
    {
        int indexOfLastInstance = -1;

        while (true)
        {
            TextPointer next = text.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            if (next == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            TextRange newText = new TextRange(text, next);

            int index = newText.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(searchWord.ToLower());
            if (index != -1)
            {
                indexOfLastInstance = index;
            }

            if (index > 0)
            {
                TextPointer start = text.GetPositionAtOffset(index);
                TextPointer end = text.GetPositionAtOffset(index + searchWord.Length);
                TextRange textRange = new TextRange(start, end);
                textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow));
            }
            text = next;
        }

        return indexOfLastInstance;
    }
```