# Find the index of an xml element in text C#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xpath

I am making a WPF app which displays XML in a FlowDocument, and a user can select an element or elements in this XML with XPath. I want to be able to highlight the value of the element that the XPath is selecting in the FlowDocument. I am currently looking at highlighting using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760702/highlight-parts-of-text-in-flowdocument). The problem is that since the FlowDocument displays a string, I need to find the index of any element(s) that the XPath represents in this string - I can't simply just search for it as text as it could produce false matches. Any suggestions how I can do this?

Comment: Which XML API are you using?

Comment: Currently storing a copy of the XML in an `XmlDocument`to find the elements via XPath

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to use LINQ to XML instead (it's a generally nicer API) and if knowing the line number and position within the line is good enough, you could use [`IXmlLineInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = XDocument.Load("test.xml", LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
        var xpath = "/root/child";
        var result = xml.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
        foreach (var element in result)
        {
            var info = (IXmlLineInfo) element;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1} {2}",
                              info.LineNumber,
                              info.LinePosition,
                              element);
        }
    }
}
```

It's entirely possible that you can use this with `XmlElement` as well, but I'm not sure how. This doesn't give you the character position, of course - but aside from anything else, you could work out the character location of the start of each line yourself *reasonably* easily. There may be something else to specify the exact character location, of course - I just haven't seen it.

Comment: If I set the text of my `FlowDocument` to the same string of text that I load into the `XDocument` (using a Stream), the `LinePosition` seems to be incorrect when doing `XPathSelectElements`

Comment: @user2609051: "Seems to be incorrect" doesn't give us much information - in particular, it's possible that the lines in the `FlowDocument` are being wrapped somewhere. Please update your question with a concrete example.